# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an rails app that only logged users can access all the application functions. It's not possible to create or remove users, only the admin can create/delete new users from command line or seed files. Ruby version is 2.5.3 and Rails is 5.2.2 with devise to authentication. From 4 days now I've been running into this issue in development:

```
Started GET "/manifest.json" for ::1 at 2020-08-16 18:53:26 -0300
Started GET "/serviceworker.js" for ::1 at 2020-08-16 18:53:28 -0300
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-08-16 18:53:29 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"****", "user"=>{"email"=>"****@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


  
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Everything was working fine before this and it started to happen without any changes in my code. This seems to happen only in development environment on **google chrome**. I've ran rails server and tested in others browsers like Opera and Firefox and the development environment still works fine in these browsers.

Some fixes that I've tried to do:

Turn off and on cookies, clear all browser data and restart pc several times, reinstall the browser, remove all turbolinks, add `rack-cors` gem and some code changes like below.

Change `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` to `protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception` in my `application_controller.rb`.

Check if `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` was present in my view. It was.

Add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` to `application_controller.rb`.

When I add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` it seems to solve the error, but the user still cannot log in. Example below:

```
Started GET "/manifest.json" for ::1 at 2020-08-16 19:12:58 -0300
Started GET "/serviceworker.js" for ::1 at 2020-08-16 19:12:59 -0300
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-08-16 19:13:05 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"****", "user"=>{"email"=>"****@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "****@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/******/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 135ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-08-16 19:13:05 -0300
Processing by PassthroughController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My application_controller.rb is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

My User.rb file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

My passthrough_controller.rb

```
class PassthroughController < ApplicationController
  def index
    path =  case current_user.port
            when '****'
              ****_map_path
            when '***'
              ***_map_path
            else
              new_user_session_path
            end
    redirect_to path
  end
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      get '****/map', to: '****#map'
      get '****/report', to: '****#report'
      get '***/map', to:'***#map'
      get '***/report', to:'***#report'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'passthrough#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
      get '****/map', to: 'passthrough#index'
      get '****/report', to: 'passthrough#index'
      get '***/map', to: 'passthrough#index'
      get '***/report', to: 'passthrough#index'
    end
  end
end
                  
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
                     root GET    /                                                                                        passthrough#index
                 ****_map GET    /****/map(.:format)                                                                      ****#map
              ****_report GET    /****/report(.:format)                                                                   ****#report
                  ***_map GET    /***/map(.:format)                                                                       ***#map
               ***_report GET    /***/report(.:format)                                                                    ***#report
     unauthenticated_root GET    /                                                                                        passthrough#index
                          GET    /****/map(.:format)                                                                      passthrough#index
                          GET    /****/report(.:format)                                                                   passthrough#index
                          GET    /***/map(.:format)                                                                       passthrough#index
                          GET    /***/report(.:format)                                                                    passthrough#index
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

This is my new user session form:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {id: "login-form"} ) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :email,
                  required: false,
                  autofocus: true,
                  input_html: { autocomplete: "email" } %>
      <%= f.input :password,
                  label: 'Password',
                  required: false,
                  input_html: { autocomplete: "current-password" } %>
      <%= f.input :remember_me, label: 'Remember me', as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions session-btn">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Submit" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This is my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <%= render 'shared/head' %>
    <meta property="og:title" content="****" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="*****" />
    <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="******">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <%= favicon_link_tag asset_path('icon.png') %>
    <title>****</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <% exclude_navbar_from_views = ['sessions', 'passwords', 'registrations'] %>
    <% if exclude_navbar_from_views.include?(controller_name) %>
      <%= yield %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
      <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>
      <%= yield %>
    <% end %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello. While setting up `devise`, did you create something like a SECRET_KEY?

Comment: No devise secret_key was created. In devise.rb file I have this line commented:   # config.secret_key = '****'

Comment: Sorry, that's on for Rails APIs. Let's see your `application.html.erb`.

Comment: Just edited the post with my application.html.erb

Comment: Try addign this again `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`, but this time add `, :only  => :create`

So that's `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create`

Comment: By adding:  `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create` or similars I get an `Completed 401 Unauthorized` and user does not log in

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira Is your new user session form opening in modal (popup) ?

Comment: For 401 error, you need to skip `before_action :authenticate_user!` from ApplicationController for devise_controllers.
 `before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :devise_controller?`

Comment: @AnandBait thanks for your advice. I'm not using any modals and i'm still getting 401 error even using `before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :devise_controller?`.

Comment: I think this has something to do with devise_for and devise_scope used in routes. Please check [this discussion](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/2840) once and see if it solves your issue

Comment: @AnandBait no lucky with that too =(

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @axelmukwena never ):

Comment: Actually, I tried `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]` yesterday and it worked. Though be careful if you're hosting sensitive data, [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html). I'm just building a community-ran site soo